# howto cut text from specific character in sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLITE Query question:
I have a query which returns string with the character '#' in it.
I would like to remove all characters after this specific character '#':

```
select field from mytable;
```

result :

```
text#othertext
text2#othertext
text3#othertext
```

So in my sample I would like to create a query which only returns :

```
text
text2
text3
```

I tried something with instr() to get the index, but instr() was not recognized as a function -> SQL Error: no such function: instr (probably old version of db . sqlite_version()-> 3.7.5).

Any hints howto achieve this ?

Comment: Why can't you update the DB version?

Comment: Moreover, if you had problems because it might be an older version and you probably are not able to update it, you should at least tell us which version you're running

Comment: Something like SUBSTRING(column FROM 1 FOR POSITION(column,'#')-1)?

Comment: Question updated with the sqlite version : sqlite_version()->
3.7.5

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. You can `rtrim` the string of all characters other than the `#` character.

   This assumes, of course, that (a) there is only one `#` in the string; and (b) that you're dealing with simple strings (e.g. 7-bit ASCII) in which it is easy to list all the characters to be stripped.
2. You can use `sqlite3_create_function` to create your own rendition of `INSTR`. The specifics here will vary a bit upon how you're using